# Windows 7 folder is getting weird

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

This is annoying, I want this:

[image: [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/15edcoj.png[/IMG]]

to become this:

[image: [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/ra947m.png[/IMG]]

I really hate the thumbnail, I want it everything in one folder without folder in folder...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to remove grouping.  Right click in the files pane, click "Group by", then "(none)".